# Discern and perform an operation on a list

Tags: javascript

I have some code that's meant to discern certain words in a list and then based on which word is in the list, do a mathematical operation on the numbers also found in the list. Here's my code:

```
  for (op in operations) {
    if (arrayses.letteros.indexOf(op) !== -1) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    var result = arrayses.numeros[0];
    while (i < arrayses.numeros.length) {
      if (i === 0) {
        result = arrayses.numeros[0];
      } else {
        result = operations[op](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);
      }
      i += 1;
    }
```

The part of the code I'm having trouble with is the very first line up there. My program has to pass JSLint based on the assumption I'm using a browser and tolerating multiple variables and whitespace mess. JSLint says the for in my for...in statement up there is unexpected; are there any alternatives to using that statement? It's used to look for the operations listed above my function in a global variable.

Here's where operations is defined, it's a global variable:

```
var operations = {      
  add: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return Number(a) + Number(b);
  },
  subtract: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a - b;
  },
  multiply: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a * b;
  },
  divide: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a / b;

  }
};
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: We are here to review the original code that you posted. Don't change your question by incorporating advice from an answer — it's confusing and unfair.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.keys` and `Array#some` to determine if any key in an object fits your criteria:

```
found = Object.keys(operations).some((op) => arrayses.letteros.indexOf(op) !== -1);
```

In general, you can use `Object.keys` and array iteration methods (`forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `some`, `every`, etc.) to replace `for..in` loops.

Comment: Okay I'm new to Javascript, is that jquery or regex? I don't want to use either of those yet if it is.

Comment: @Giverbud It's neither. They're just built-in functions that should be supported everywhere without dependencies.

Comment: Okay now I've put that into my code, but when I run my program, the web console tells me operations[op] is not a function. I can edit my original post to show you where I put your code in my code if you'd like

Comment: Go for it. The only time `Object.keys` won't work is when you're trying to iterate over properties added to an object's prototype.

Comment: Okay it's been edited. At this point I figure I just put it in the wrong place or something, but I have no idea.

Comment: I'll need to see where `operations` is defined.

Comment: Okay I'll put that up above, too; sorry for the long wait

Comment: Alright the edit's up for where operations is defined, thank you for your patience.

Comment: I should clarify that op is defined as a variable in the function that contains the statement I was trying to correct